# what does "and into" mean

Tags: idioms

Please forgive me if this question is so silly, I understand the whole text except the bold part:

> Freddie Mercury moved out of the flat they shared together **and into
>   12** Stafford Terrace in Kensington, and bought Austin a place of her
>   own nearby.

Also, what is that "12"?
-- Thanks

Comment: Freddy Mercury *moved out of* [some place] *and into* [some place].

Comment: **Please forgive me**? I forgave you for this time only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*12 Stafford Terrace* is an address: *12* is the street number, *Stafford Terrace* the name of the street.

*Into* is a preposition, corresponding to *out of* earlier; the two preposition phrases headed by these are conjoined with *and* just as the two main clauses are:

```
                       out of the flat they shared together
Freddie Mercury moved   and
                       into   12 Stafford Terrace in Kensington  
                 and
                bought Austin a place of her own nearby.
```